# Strange characters inserted before username both in Terminal and Tilda terminal emulator

Tags: command-line, special-characters, character-set, tilda

Started noticing some odd behavior when using Gnome Terminal, Tilda terminal emulator also a couple days ago. Basically whenever I launch a fresh instance of either application (new tabs also) I get these strange characters inserted before my username. It is as though the character encoding is off base? Or maybe the font I'm using? I doubt the latter case as previously I was using the exact same font w/ no probs.

Check out the shots to see what I mean (see red thin border). Apologies for the fugly links, don't have enough rep yet to post images directly:

**Tilda**

 
[image]

**Gnome Terminal**

[image]

If I hit the `Esc` key or clear the terminal via the `clear` command, these characters go away.

**What on earth could be causing this? And more importantly, how the hell do I get rid of or restore to original condition?**

Yes I have messed around w/ fonts, restarted, purged both applications and the issue still persists!

Guys, I'd really appreciate your knowledge and help on this.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give little more detail about how you changed your font ?

Comment: 2 questions: (1) If you hit Enter do you see the funny character, i.e. is it part of the prompt? (2) if you type `bash` after `clear` would you see them again?

Comment: What's the output of `echo $PS1`?

Comment: For everybody that responded to my post, many thanks, I highly appreciate it.